# How to capture "Go" key in a Phonegap application running on a Kindle Fire?

Tags: android, cordova, kindle-fire

My web app has a handler that listens for what key is pressed and responds accordingly.

```
handler: function(event) {
    if (event.which === Constants.ENTER_KEY) {
        ...
    }
}
```

`Constants.ENTER_KEY` is 13

This is my input field (in JSX):

```
<input id="some-id" onKeyDown={this.handler} />
```

Now, I'm converting my web app to a mobile app that runs on a Kindle Fire.
Instead of an "Enter" key, I now have "Go". Examining that event, I see that

`which: 0`, `charCode: 0`, `keyCode: 0`, `key: 'Unidentified'`.

In fact, every key I tested results in `event.which: 0`

How do I capture "Go"?

Since I believe FireOS is built on top of Android, I'll investigate Android solutions. I will update with what I find out.

**Edit:**
The key needs to be detected in a `<input>`. Maybe I should wrap a `<form>` around it and listen for an `onSubmit`...

**Edit 2:**
I posted a solution, but would like an explanation regarding why it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, this is bizarre.

Changing `onKeyDown` to `onKeyPress` fixes it. Not sure why.

`which: 13, charCode: 13, keyCode: 0, key: 'Enter'`

**Edit:**
After changing to `onKeyPress`, it seems like `handler` is only entered when I press "Go".